# Find maximum area of rectangle in histogram

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

Im working on this problem: Find the largest rectangle in histogram.

The main idea is :

```
For example: you have 5 vertical reactangles with lengh : 3 4 5 6 3
Output the largest area in horizontal direction

using stack:
    First loop:
    First, put indexes of histogram respectively in stack:
        Store top of the stack, the POP it.
        3-> [0] ....
        6-> [3]
        i++;
        If input is larger than the top of the stack, POP the top and calculate the area 
            Area can be calculated by : 
                - If stack is empty now, AREA = histogram[value of the last top] * i;  
                - If it is not, AREA = histogram[value of the last top] * (i - value of the current top - 1)
                Compare AREA with max --> max;

    Second loop:
        Check if stack is empty:
            Store top of the stack, the POP it.
            - If stack is empty now, AREA = histogram[value of the last top] * n;
            - If not, AREA = histogram[value of the last top] * (i - value of the current top - 1)
            Compare AREA with max --> max
```

So, I wrote a function to print max area that we can find:

```
void LargestRectangle (int hist[]){
    int max = 0;
    int area;
    int i = 0;
    int top;
    int pop;
    while (i<n){
        if (EmptyStackCheck(sTack) || hist[TopValue(&sTack)] <= hist[i]){
            PushStack(&sTack, i);
            i++;
        }else {
            top = TopValue(&sTack); 
            pop = PopStack(&sTack);
            if(EmptyStackCheck(sTack)){
                area = hist[top] * i;
            }else area = hist[top] = (i - TopValue(&sTack) - 1);
            if (area > max) max = area;
        }

    }
    while (!EmptyStackCheck(sTack)){
        top = TopValue(&sTack); 
        pop = PopStack(&sTack);
        if(EmptyStackCheck(sTack)){
                area = hist[top] * i;
        }else area = hist[top] = (i - TopValue(&sTack) - 1);
        if (area > max) max = area;
    }
    printf("%d", max);
}
```

p/s: Ignore the pop variable
I use `top` to store the top value of the stack. `TopValue` is a function I write which return top value of the stack.

But the problem is, when I run the program, nothing happended. So can u guys help me checking my false in it pls?

Bonus: Some of my function implementation:

```
typedef struct StackNode{
    int data;
    struct StackNode* next;
}StackNode;

StackNode* newStack(int data){
    StackNode* newstack = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    newstack->data = data;
    newstack->next = NULL;
    return newstack;
}

int EmptyStackCheck(StackNode* stack){
    return !stack;
}

void PushStack(StackNode** stack, int n){
    StackNode* newstack = newStack(n);
    newstack->next = *stack;
    *stack = newstack;
}

int PopStack(StackNode** stack){
    StackNode* newstack = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    newstack = *stack;
    *stack = (*stack)->next;
    int popData = newstack->data;
    free(newstack);
    return popData;
}

int TopValue(StackNode** stack){
    StackNode* newstack = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    newstack = *stack;
    while(newstack->next->next){
        newstack = newstack->next;
    }
    return newstack->data;
}
```

Comment: I think you are too much asking to ignore code. Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: "when I run the program, nothing happended" isn't doing enough.  Add print statements or use a debugger to find out where and what.  Then come back with detailed question(s).